# Snowflake use variable to set Database and Schema

Tags: variables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, worksheet

I'm trying to create a variable in Snowflake UI worksheet and use the same in my queries to execute.

Below is a sample query and the error I'm getting. Any workaround to achieve this ?

```
  SET Database_pre= 'Sample_Pre';  
  SET Schema_pre='ACCOUNT';  
  SET Database_post= 'Sample_Post';   
  SET Schema_post='ACCOUNT';   
  SELECT * FROM   $Database_pre.$Schema_pre."PRODUCT" 
  EXCEPT 
  SELECT * FROM   $Database_post.$Schema_post."PRODUCT"
```

This is the error I'm getting while running the above query
Error - SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 16 unexpected '$Database_pre'. syntax error line 3 at position 16 unexpected '$Database_post'.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html#using-variables-in-sql

You need to use IDENTIFIER() or TABLE() round your variables

Comment: Could you kindly give an example from my above scenario. I tried Table() but it didn't work 
    SET Database_pre= 'Sample_pre';
    SET Schema_pre='ACCOUNT';
    SET Database_post= 'Sample_Post';
    SET Schema_post='ACCOUNT';

    SELECT * FROM TABLE($$Database_pre.Schema_pre.PRODUCT$$)

Comment: Hi - why are you using double $ signs? Why are you using $ signs round a combination of two variables (the db and schema)  and a literal (the table)?

Answer (score 1):

try this , it should work.

```
create table PRODUCT (fld1 varchar2(100), fld2 varchar2(100));
create table PRODUCT_COPY (fld1 varchar2(100), fld2 varchar2(100));

SET Database_pre = 'Database1';  
SET Schema_pre='SCH'; 
SET TGT_TABLE1='PRODUCT'

SET Database_post= 'Database1';   
SET Schema_post='SCH'; 
SET TGT_TABLE2='PRODUCT_COPY'

set t=$Database_pre||'.'||$Schema_pre||'.'||$TGT_TABLE1;
set t1=$Database_post||'.'||$Schema_post||'.'||$TGT_TABLE2;
 
 
 select * from identifier($t)
 EXCEPT
  select * from identifier($t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal

```html
set schema_name = 'my_db.my_schema';

set table_name = 'my_table';

use schema identifier($schema_name);

select * from identifier($table_name) order by 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**